# Factorizing Determinants

Tags: determinant

I don't know how to factorize the determinants. Please help.

1.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a+b &b+c &c+a\\
b+c &c+a &a+b\\
c+a &a+b &b+c
\end{vmatrix}
$$
2.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 &b^2 &c^2\\
b^2 &c^2 &a^2\\
c^2 &a^2 &b^2
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: What exactly don't you know? Do you know what is the determinant of a matrix and how to compute it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add  the two last columns to the first one and then subtruct the first row from the two other rows. Now developp along the first column to find
   $$2(a+b+c)\left[-(a-b)^2-(b-c)(a-c)\right]$$
2. Repeat the same idea as in 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Saruss' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) you should easily see that the determinant of a matrix of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}x&y&z\\y&z&x\\z&x&y\end{matrix}\right)$$
is $3xyz-x^3-y^3-z^3$.

Can you use this to solve your problems?